# (Javascript) How to get object properties to csv with header and empty strings in the csv when the property doesnt exist?

Tags: javascript, csv

I have an array of objects. Some of these objects have shared properties, but not every object has every property, and the properties may be in different order from object to object. Consider the following:

```
var arr = [{ foo: 1, bar: 2}, { foo: 3, thing: 4}, {thing: 5, bar: 6}]
```

I need to convert this array into a CSV so that the first row is a header with all of the property names, and if the property exists in the object, it will be populated, otherwise be an empty string. The order doesnt necessarily matter, as long as the order for each item in each row is consistent with the order of the header.

Desired output:

```
foo,bar,thing
1,2,
3,,4
,6,5
```

Comment: What determines the order of the headings? Note that objects do not have order so that can't be relied on. Also please show what you have tried. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my answer using json2csv. https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv

Thanks everyone!

Here's my snippet for anyone that needs/wants it.

```
//gets the unique headers from the array.
var header = Object.keys(downloadData.reduce(function (result, obj) {
            return Object.assign(result, obj);
        }, {}));
//this part uses the json2csv library linked above
var csv = json2csv({ data: downloadData, fields: header });

//the rest of this prompts the user to download the file.
filename = 'export.csv';

if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
    csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csv;
}
data = encodeURI(csv);

link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', data);
link.setAttribute('download', filename);
document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF
link.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCsvLines(input) {

    var CSV_SEPARATOR = ',';

    var headers = getHeaders(input);

    var lines = getLines(input, headers);

    return [headers.join(CSV_SEPARATOR)].concat(lines);

    function getHeaders(input) {

        var headers = new Set();

        input.forEach(function (obj) {
            Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
                headers.add(key);
            });
        });

        return Array.from(headers);
    }

    function getLines(input, headers) {

        var lines = [];

        input.forEach(function (obj) {
            var line = [];
            headers.forEach(function (head) {
                line.push(obj[head] || '');
            });
            lines.push(line);
        });

        return lines.map(function(line) {
            return line.join(CSV_SEPARATOR);
        });
    }
}

getCsvLines(arr); // -> ["foo,bar,thing", "1,2,", "3,,4", ",6,5"]
```

The `getCsvLines` function returns array of lines of csv for export.

To change values' order just reorder `headers` array before passing it to `getLines`.

Answer (score -1):

This will help get you started

```js
var arr = [{ foo: 1, bar: 2}, { foo: 3, thing: 4}, {thing: 5, bar: 6}];

var fields = arr.reduce((a, c, arrIdx, arr) => {
  Object.keys(c).forEach(key => {
    a[key] = a[key] || new Array(arr.length).fill('');
    a[key][arrIdx] = c[key].toString();
  })
  return a
}, {});

// not sure what determines sort order of headings/columns
var headings = Object.keys(fields).sort();

var csv = mapToCsvLine(headings);
csv += headings.reduce((a, c) => {
  return a + mapToCsvLine(fields[c]);
}, '');

//flattens array to quoted strings and line break
function mapToCsvLine(arr) {
  var csvDelimiter = ',';
  return arr.map(val => JSON.stringify(val)).join(csvDelimiter) + '\n';
}


console.log(csv)
```